# Upward infinite scroll for bottom-first-populated UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to build an instant messenger similar to Facebook Messenger, with newest messages at the bottom and older messages being loaded when the user scrolls upward.

Thanks to many other posts on Stackoverflow, I could get infinite scrolling and bottom-first-populated tables working. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get both of them working at the same time.

For infinite scroll, I'm using these codes:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maxOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
    if (maxOffset - contentOffset) <= (scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.2 {
        // Code for loading more data
    }
}
```

I've also worked with this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (self.newsfeeds.count - indexPath.row) < 4 {
        // Code for loading more data
    }
}
```

For bottom-first-populated table, I'm using this simple code in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`:

```
let message = messages[messages.count - 1 - indexPath.row]
```

paired with this line in `viewWillAppear`

```
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.messages.count - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
```

To describe in words, if the user reaches certain cell or y position, the app will load more data. But my bottom-first-populated table works by adding reversely ordered data to cells from top to bottom, and then immediately scrolling down to the bottom to display that region.

So the app hits the top of the table and then immediately hit the bottom of the table, repeatedly triggering the code that loads more data like some madman.

Is there any other way to implement bottom-first-populated table or some way to disentangle this mess? I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: To fill from the bottom, rotate and flip the table view and then each cell, as it's added to the table.  This way index 0,0 will be displayed at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Avi oh I had a glance at that solution, but thought it seemed too hacky and unnecessarily complicated so I decided to skip it. i mean, that solution feels like using double negative in sentences. i'll look around a bit more for something else, but will return to your solution if nothing good comes up. thank you very much!